# Matching numbers with glob pattern

Tags: bash, wildcards

I am trying to match using a glob pattern.  However, this match is failing:

```bash
dgt='^+([0123456789])$'
[[ "$1" == $dgt  ]] && echo "SUCCESS" || echo "FAILURE"
```

Comment: It's unclear what you want to do and what your example should print. You have an expression that looks like a mix between an extended globbing pattern and a regular expression, but you try to use it as if it was a globbing pattern.

Comment: I want to match positive integers such as `12`, `345`, `23456`. `dgt` is not matching if `$1=23`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your pattern, `^+([0123456789])$`, is a mix of an extended globbing pattern and a regular expression.  A globbing pattern does not need to be anchored explicitly, as it is always anchored anyway.  Therefore, a globbing pattern starting with `^` and ending with `$` would match those literal characters at the start and end of a string.  If you want to use a globbing pattern and don't want to match `^` at the start and `$` at the end, remove these.

You will end up with the following code:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# Bash releases earlier than 4.1 needs to enable the extglob shell
# option.  For release 4.1+, the pattern used in [[ ]] is assumed
# to be an extended globbing pattern.
#
# shopt -s extglob

pattern='+([0123456789])'

if [[ $1 == $pattern ]]; then
   echo 'contains only digits'
else
   echo 'contains non-digit or is empty'
fi
```

In a shell with no extended globbing patterns, it's easier to match non-digits:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

case $1 in
    *[!0123456789]*)
        echo 'contains non-digit' ;;
    '')
        echo 'is empty' ;;
    *)
        echo 'contains only digits'
esac
```

In the `bash` shell, you can use the above code too, as it portable and would work in all `sh`-compatible shells, or you could use

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

pattern='*[!0123456789]*'

if [[ $1 == $pattern ]]; then
   echo 'contains non-digit'
elif [ -z "$1" ]; then
   echo 'is empty'
else
   echo 'contains only digits'
fi
```

Comment: What is the purpose of enclosing the pattern with `*` at each end?

Comment: @Veak `*[!0123456789]*` matches a non-digit anywhere in a string. `[!0123456789]` matches a string consisting of a single non-digit character.  The `*` at the start and end of the pattern allows the non-digit character to exists anywhere in the string, if it exists at all.

Comment: `[[` doesn't need `shopt -s extglob` to use extglob

Comment: @rowboat Testing on `bash` 5.1.12 shows that the shell option needs to be set to be able to use extended globbing patterns like `+(...)`, also within `[[ ... ]]`.

Comment: @rowboat I see now. It's the assignment of the pattern to the variable that isn't allowed if `exglob` isn't set, unless the pattern is quoted. This seem to me a bug as there is no globbing happening in the assignment.  Thanks for the heads-up and for getting me to investigate this further.

Comment: That `extglob` is in effect by default inside `[[...]]` is "new" since 4.1. You'd still need `shopt -s extglob` with the ancient bash found on macos.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks, and I'm withdrawing my statement above about it being a bug that I can't do `variable=+(a|b|c)` without `extglob` set, because it's not the fact that it's an extended globbing pattern that is the issue, it's the parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

If glob pattern matching is not absolutely required, you can alternatively use regular expressions instead.

With Bash you can use the `=~` regex operator:

```
dgt='^[[:digit:]]+$'
[[ "$1" =~ $dgt ]] && echo "SUCCESS" || echo "FAILURE"
```

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. Corrected.

Comment: Does the matching of more characters than just 0123456789 happen in Ubuntu?

Comment: Is there a way to detect when `[0-9]` matches more characters?

Comment: @Veak, Try `perl -XC -e 'for ($i = 1; $i <= 0x10ffff; $i++) {$i=0xe000 if $i==0xd800; print chr$i}' | bash -c 'while IFS= read -rN1 c; do [[ $c =~ [0-9] ]] && printf %s "$c"; done` in a UTF-8 locale for instance. On Ubuntu 20.04 and in a `en_GB.UTF-8` locale, I find that it matches over a thousand different characters.  `[[:digit:]]` can also match characters other than 0123456789 on some systems, though not current versions of Ubuntu AFAIK.

Comment: In the case of `=~`, it's down to the system's regexp libraries. You'll get the same behaviour with zsh unless the `rematchpcre` option is enabled. For globs though, in the case of bash, [it can get even worse](https://www.mail-archive.com/bug-bash@gnu.org/msg25885.html)

Comment: With your command I got `<`.  Perhaps something wrong with the bash command?

Comment: @Veak the closing single quote is missing at the end

Comment: I do have some complicated expressions for floating point numbers:  `flp='?([-+])*([0-9])?([.,])+([0-9])?([eE]?([-+])+([0-9]))'`.  The solution is to use `[0123456789]` which gets the expression quite long.  Is there a nice and readable way to split this (perhaps with the exponential part introduced seperately).

Comment: I tried it with `export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8` and I have only got `0123456789`.